# Почему блоки с одинаковыми стилями выглядят по разному?

Tags: html, css, 3d

По какой-то причине отступ слева от красного блока больше, чем отступ справа, хотя стили блоков по бокам по сути одинаковы, за исключением того, что один повернут в одну сторону по оси Y, а второй в другую.

Как исправить такую проблему?

```css
.block {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper {
  perspective: 500px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.block1 {
  background: url('https://cdn.wallpapershdin.com/wallpapers/eiffel-tower-paris-monument-2400x1350.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  transform: rotateY(-10deg);
}

.block3 {
  background: url('https://cdn.wallpapershdin.com/wallpapers/eiffel-tower-paris-monument-2400x1350.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  transform: rotateY(10deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block1 block"></div>
  <div class="block2 block"></div>
  <div class="block3 block"></div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Используй `display:flex` для wrapper

https://jsfiddle.net/Ldens9gw/1/

Answer (score 0):

```css
.reset {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.a{
  position: absolute;
}

:root {
  --w: 400px;
  --w2: calc(var(--w) / 3);
}

.wrapper {
  perspective: calc(var(--w) / 10);
  margin-top: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: calc(var(--w));
  height: 100px;
}

.block {
  width: var(--w2);
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.block1 {
  background: url('https://cdn.wallpapershdin.com/wallpapers/eiffel-tower-paris-monument-2400x1350.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  transform: rotateY(-10deg);
  left: 0;
}

.block2 {
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
  left: var(--w2);
}

.block3 {
  background: url('https://cdn.wallpapershdin.com/wallpapers/eiffel-tower-paris-monument-2400x1350.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  transform: rotateY(10deg);
  left: calc(var(--w2) * 2);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper reset">
  <div class="block1 block reset a"></div>
  <div class="block2 block reset a"></div>
  <div class="block3 block reset a"></div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="wrapper reset">
  <div class="block reset"></div>
  <div class="block reset"></div>
  <div class="block reset"></div>
</div>
```